# Magento makes use of properties in a non PHP native way. Where is that hard coded?

Tags: layout, magento-1, model

Examples are abundant: `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');`

While the method takes 2 arguments separated by a comma. Not in the above example.

What turns `'core/layout'` into `$arg1,$arg2`?

Answer (score 1):

These are not two arguments, it is one argument, namely the class alias.

It is evaluated in [`Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php#L1219), where it is turned into a real class name based on module configurations.

`Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')` eventually results in a call to `getGroupedClassName('model', 'core/layout')` when it is used the first time. On later calls, `getSingleton()` returns the same instance, which is stored in the global registry. There, `'core/layout'` is also used as part of a registry key, `"_singleton/core/layout"`